# Converting variable width font to monospaced bitmap font

Tags: xcode, bitmap, truetype, fixed-width, monospace

I've been working on an iPhone game and ran across a problem. I got a nice (variable width) ttf font which I'd like to convert to bitmap, but every generator I find keeps it variable width. How can I get myself a fixed-width bitmap font (from a ttf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I redesigned my app to work with variable width fonts now. Case closed.

Answer (score 1):

It is easiest to select a monospaced font such as Courier.

The other option is to space each letter out yourself. THe spacing will have to be a bit wider than the width of 'W'.

Comment: Even if I select a monospaced font like Courier (yes I've tried this) those apps keep cutting the sides off. And the second option is really tedious and also my last resort.

Comment: don't you mean the spacing of 'W' instead of it's width? (it seems a little much)

Comment: doing myself for the gnu Unifont is really going to take a lot of time *(more than 70,000 glyph)*.